# KWin начинает работать слишком медленно после выхода из полноэкранного режима

Tags: kde, x11

Как я понял kwin перезапускается и начинает зависать (работает, но очень медленно) помогает только выход из сессии (перезапуск kwin в ручную не помогает). Причём же происходит только на x11, на wayland, такого нет. Но на wayland пока не хочу переходить(одно только отсутствие главного экрана останавливает). Есть ли варианты это решить? Kwin 5.23.4, Kernel 5.15.12, Fedora 35,KDE Frameworks 5.89

P.S. если нужны логи, то скажите где из взять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переходом на OpenGL 3.1 в настройках графических эфектов